# Launcher or home screen which simply populates the home screen with the most frequently used apps for Android

Tags: android, launcher

I'm tiered of organizing my apps. I most often use "Gesture Search" by Google, and notice that it gets most the apps I need on the first letter I write - the results are also ordered by what seems like frequency of use. I don't use all that many apps, and I am sure a home screen which simply shows me the apps I most often use on the home screen would be enough for me.

Anybody heard about such a thing? Most launcher's I've seen are packed with features. I just want something very simple.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but take a look at [Smart Launcher 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerfree). Moreover: If you know which apps you want to see, and they do not change frequently, many launchers allow you to "hide unwanted apps" from being displayed. Check [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher#group_523) for more alternatives :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the suggestion. I don't use a lot of apps, but I do switch them out often. Trying new things. My usage pattern change and I don't want to have an "app cleanup chore" every Sunday. I really just want the phone to keep the 12 or so apps I usually access be available at one click.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend

[**Z Launcher**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nokia.z&hl=en)

Z Launche helps you find anything faster on your phone be it apps, contacts or even websites. **It places you most used apps on the home screen** while everything else is just a scribble away. You also have the option of pinning apps to the dock area just like your standard Android launcher

https://www.zlauncher.com/